# Properly adding functions within function

Tags: php, function, codeigniter

I'm creating a profile script where users can edit their personal info, interests, and links.

I had all the fields in one form but now I want to separate them by tabs. So I will have a personal info tab, interests tab, and links tab. In each page I will have a form submitting data to the corresponding function. For example if you're editing the personal info the form will direct to `mysite.com/edit/personal_info`

The functions should look like this

```
function edit() {

   function personal_info() {
      //data
   }   

   function interests() {
     //data
   }

   function links() {
     //data
   }

}
```

I'm not sure how to properly send data from the edit() function to all its sub functions.

I'm adding the general data below to all my function but I want to add it once and all the functions should have it. I'm also trying to avoid global variables.

```
$this->db->where('user_id', $this->tank_auth->get_user_id());
$query = $this->db->get('user_profiles');
$data['row'] = $query->row();
```

Then in each sub function I have validation rules (codeigniter) Below are the rules for the personal_info function

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'First Name', 'trim|required|xss_clean|min_length[2]|max_length[20]|alpha');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', 'Last Name', 'trim|required|xss_clean|min_length[2]|max_length[20]|alpha');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('gender', 'Gender', 'trim|required|xss_clean|alpha');
```

and a statement to add the data to the database or return an error if validation rules fail

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) //if validation rules fail
        {           
            $this->load->view('edit_profile', $data);
        }
        else //success
        {
        $data = array (                 
                'first_name'    => $this->input->post('first_name'),
                'last_name'     => $this->input->post('last_name'),
                'gender'    => $this->input->post('gender')

            );
            $this->load->model('Profile_model');
            $this->Profile_model->profile_update($data);            
        }
```

How can I properly create these sub function without repeating code in each one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, you kind of lost me.  Why are you using functions within functions?  If you're using CodeIgniter, those functions should be within a class:

```
class Edit extends CI_Controller {
  function personal_info() {
    /* Do personal info stuff. */
  }

  function interests() {
    /* Do interests stuff. */
  }

  function links() {
    /* Do links stuff. */
  }

  function _common() {
    // The underscore makes the function not available to browse, but you can
    // put common code here that is called within the other functions by
    // invoking $this->_common();
  }
}
```

Comment: That would, of course, be in a file named controllers/edit.php.  For more information, I encourage you to check out the documentation for controllers at this site: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html

Comment: Thank you for the example! I had forgotten about classes in CI. I used `$this->_common();` as instructed and it works! :)

Comment: Glad it works, and good luck with your site!  I use CodeIgniter quite a bit, and I think you'll find it a handy framework to use.

Answer (score 2):

by the way your code is made, it looks like you're using codeigniter.

When you request mysite.com/edit/personal_info, it will request a controller called edit, and a function called personal_info, so you don't need a function inside a function, you just need functions inside of the edit controller class. Further url segments will be passed to the function as arguments.